# django project deployed on AWS using postgres - how to create a database

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a django project that I deployed on AWS using the awsebcli.

I need to provision a database (postgres) and once the enviroment is deployed I create from the console a database
I would like to automate this process and I tried a config file

so I tried adding this to my django.config file inside the .ebextensions folder of my project:

```
  aws:rds:dbinstance:
    DBAllocatedStorage: '5'
    DBDeletionPolicy: Delete
    DBEngine: postgres
    DBEngineVersion: 10.17
    DBInstanceClass: db.t2.micro
    DBPassword: PASSWORD_HERE
    DBUser: USERNAME_HERE
    MultiAZDatabase: false
```

But in this way the database is not created. I have to created it from the console and then pass as enviromental variables using the terminal (eb setenv) the endpoint of the database and other parameters.

Is there a way to solve this and automate the deployment?

-----EDIT-----
This is my full django.config file

```
 option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "personal_portfolio.settings"
    PYTHONPATH: "/var/app/current:$PYTHONPATH"
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME: "insert-bucketname"
    AWS_S3_REGION_NAME: "us-east-1"
    RDS_USERNAME: "xxxx"
    RDS_PASSWORD: "xxxx"
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: "personal_portfolio.wsgi:application"
    NumProcesses: 3
    NumThreads: 20
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default:
    HealthCheckPath: "/about"
    MatcherHTTPCode: "200-499"
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    /static: static
    /media: media
  aws:rds:dbinstance:
    DBAllocatedStorage: 5
    DBDeletionPolicy: Delete
    DBEngine: postgres
    DBEngineVersion: 10.17
    DBInstanceClass: db.t2.micro
    DBPassword: lorokpopen
    DBUser: postgres
    MultiAZDatabase: false
container_commands:
  01_makemigrations:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python3 manage.py makemigrations --noinput"
    leader_only: true
  02_migrate:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python3 manage.py migrate --noinput"
    leader_only: true
  03_createsu:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python3 manage.py createsu"
  04_collectstatic:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
    leader_only: true
```

Answer (score 0):

are you using `option_settings` namespace first?

**.ebextensions/db-instance-options.config**

```yaml
option_settings:
  aws:rds:dbinstance:
    DBAllocatedStorage: 100
```

as described on:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.db.html#using-features.managing.db.namespace

this page lists all values for `aws:rds:dbinstance`:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-rdsdbinstance

now, from a general best practices, this works great for development and testing environments. However, it isn't ideal for a production environment because it ties the lifecycle of the database instance to the lifecycle of your application's environment.

you should decouple your database instance from your environment, you can create the database instance in Amazon RDS via CloudFormation or CLI and configure your application to connect to it on launch, in the same way you are doing right now

in this page aws say a few things about that:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html

have a look on RDS Instance CloudFormation definition:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html

Comment: I edited the question inserting my full config file